# Eonasdan DateTimePicker - get displayed date(year/month)

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

Is there anyway to get the currently displayed month and year?
Ideally, for me, this would be available in the update event.
I can see that the "change" attribute of the update event is set to "M" when changing months, however I can't find the currently displayed month and year. Is this available anywhere?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with displayed month and year?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest. So, when the calendar is displayed, it displays one month at a time. You can use the next and previous controls to change the month (and also change the year, etc). I'd like to know which month (and year) is currently displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current value of the datetimepicker using the [`date()`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) function:

> Returns the component's model current date, a `moment` object or `null` if not set.

Then you can use momentjs function, such as [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/), [`year()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/) to get readable info about the selected date.

If you want to know the displayed year/month when the user browes the component using previous and next button, you can add a listner to [`dp.update`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpupdate) event.

> Fired (in most cases) when the `viewDate` changes. E.g. Next and Previous buttons, selecting a year.

The `viewDate` property of the events is a moment object representing the current view date. Again you can use moment functions to show info about the view date.

Here a live example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false
}).on('dp.update', function(e){
  console.log("Displayed year/month " + e.viewDate.format("YYYY MMMM"));
})

function getDate(){
  var selDate = $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date();
  if(selDate){
    console.log("Displayed year/month " + selDate.format("YYYY MMMM"));
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getDate()">Get date</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks, the `viewDate` property on the `dp.update` event was what I was looking for.  
I notice the `dp.update` event doesn't fire if you select a day of the next/previous month. For example, if June 2017 is being displayed, then the 1st to the 9th of July is also displayed [if start day of the week is set to Monday]. If you click one of these July days then the date is selected and the view is changed to July 2017, however the `dp.update` event is not fired. Is this a bug?